# users not syncing between sso and jbpm

Tags: synchronization, single-sign-on, keycloak, jbpm

I've deployed JBPM and integrated with SSO (keycloak). It works but the users aren't syncing between. When I add user on JBPM it isn't appear in SSO and the users created in SSO aren't shown in JBPM. What can I troubleshoot or configure for that?

I don't know from what to start troubleshooting. Also in manual isn't anything about that.